# Differential Equations: homogenous , third order ,linear general solutions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Question given is 
$(D-1)^3y=0$
Where $D= \frac{d}{dx}$
I **know** the solution is $(A + Bx +Cx^2)e^x $
I do not **understand why** this is the case.
I've been trying to find a good proof and a way to relate it to other differential equations but I have been unable to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's look at $(D-1)^2 y =0$.  We can write this as the *system of equations* $(D-1)z =0$ and $(D-1)y =z$, which we can solve as follows.  For $z$ we have $z' = z$, so $z = A e^x$.  Then $y'-y = A e^x$.  Multiplying by $e^{-x}$ shows that $(y e^{-x})' = A$, and so $y e^{-x} = Ax + B$, and thus $y = (Ax + B)e^x$.

Now consider $(D-1)^3 y =0$.  We write this as the system $(D-1)^2 z =0$ and $(D-1)y =z$.  From the above analysis we know $z = (Ax + B) e^x$.  Then $y' - y = (Ax + B) e^x$, and we again multiply by $e^{-x}$ to get $(y e^{-x})' = (Ax + B)$, which means $ye^{-x} = (Ax^2/2 + Bx + C)$, and thus 
$$
y = (\alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma) e^x
$$
is the general solution.

Comment: Thank you very much , extremely clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite \begin{equation}(D-1)^3y = (D-1)(D-1)^2y = 0\end{equation}
Then, you perform u substitution.
\begin{equation}
u = (D-1)y
\end{equation}
So that
\begin{equation}
(D-1)^2u = 0
\end{equation}

Now perform u' substitution
\begin{equation}
u' = (D-1)u
\end{equation}

So that
\begin{equation}
(D-1)u' = 0
\end{equation}

Then
\begin{equation}
u' = C'e^x
\end{equation}
Now,
\begin{equation}
(D-1)u = C'e^x
\end{equation}

Now, you can use an integrating factor

\begin{equation}
(Du)v - uv = C'e^xv
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
D(uv) - u(Dv) - uv = C'e^xv
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
D(uv) - u(Dv + v) = C'e^xv
\end{equation}
if we set
\begin{equation}
Dv + v = 0
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}
v = C''e^{-x}
\end{equation}

Then, you are left with
\begin{equation}
D(uC''e^{-x}) = C'
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
u = (Ax + B)e^x
\end{equation}

Substituting y back in,
\begin{equation}
(D-1)y = (Ax + B)e^x
\end{equation}

You can use the same procedure to find y, which should be easy enough at this point.